# What is the difference between 'p1connected' and 'inbound call' In Twilio API

Tags: java, twilio

I want to know the difference between `P1connected` and `InboundCall` in Twilio API.

```
switch (requestedop){
            case P1Connected:
                output = //calling a method
                break;
            case P2Connected:
                output = //calling a method
                break;
            case EndCall:
                output = //calling a method
                break;
            case TranscribeCallBack:
                output = //calling a method
                break;
            case InboundCall:
                output =//calling a method
                break;
            case InboundCallForward:
                output = //calling a method
                break;  
            case InboundSms:
                output = //calling a method
                break;
            case FallBack:
                output = //calling a method
                break;
            case MissedCall:
                output = //calling a method
                break;
            default:
                throw new ServletException ("Operation not supported.");
        }
```

I Googled it but it didn't found the exact difference in it.

Comment: Hi Amit, Where are you finding the P1Connected message? I just searched the Twilio-Java helper library and didn't find it anywhere. Also the documentation makes no mention of a P1Connected status.